# How to cancel / abort an MKNetworkOperation?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, mknetworkkit

I need to abort network operations in MKNetworkKit but can't find the methods to do that in the header files. Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

MKNetworkEngine has a method called `- (void) cancelAllOperations;`

You can see it in the [MKNetworkEngine.h](https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKNetworkKit/blob/master/MKNetworkKit/MKNetworkEngine.h) file

Answer (score 0):

If you have a handle to the network operation, you can call cancel on it.
The MKNetworkOperation inherits from NSOperation, check the implementation (.m) file, it overrides the cancel method.

Answer (score 0):

you can check

```
if([op isExecuting]){
[op cancel];
}
```

where op is instance of MkNetworkOperation.